# UISlider value assigining issue ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using a `UISlider` programmatically in a `MPMoviePlayerController` and set its value with the movie current playback time. This doesn't work properly in some cases, the value of the slider remains zero not changed with the movie's current playback time. Can anyone help me please?

My code is set to fire after each second. Both labels work properly but the `UISlider` value doesn't get updated and remains zero.

```
float playbackTime = player.currentPlaybackTime;
float duration = player.duration;
timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f   / ",playbackTime];
durationlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f",`duration];`
progressSlider.value = playbackTime;
```

Comment: In which case the issue happens ?

Comment: This would happen if the `UISliderView` `maximumValue` property is set to zero (0).  Are you sure the `maximumValue` property is set correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that player.currentPlaybackTime isn't remain 0 as well?

Comment: Please change your slider value in .1 second and tell me about your maximum value which you have defined

Comment: yeah i'm already set its maximum and minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably do this:

```
progressSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
progressSlider.maximumValue = player.duration;
```

you should do this not all the times that you update the slider but only when you initialize the slider or when you start a new video

Comment: i already set it for player but i'm facing this issue when i play other video after the previous video.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this issue by stop the video on close action of the player before play other video.
this issue occur because of previous video state in the player due to which on launching new video slider valur disturbed.